# Initializing a String on basis on java streams results in an empty String

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code in my example:

```
final List<Optional<String>> messages = 
    ImmutableList.of(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty() );

final String dummy = messages.stream()
        .filter( Optional::isPresent )
        .map( message -> message.get() )
        .collect( Collectors.joining( "\n---\n" ) );
```

Now on debugging, the value of the variable `dummy` is always an empty string. Is that a result of the stream, or the behavior of the `Collectors.joining` method?

I was under the assumption that the resultant String would be null.

Comment: what are you expecting with empty `Optional` ?

Comment: I'm expecting a null string as mentioned?

Comment: That behaviour is purely dependent on the collector you used. [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) doesn't explicitly document how it handles empty inputs, but I'm not suprised by an empty string. Indeed I wouldn't expect `null` to be returned by this ever.

Comment: I tried looking for the javadocs for the joining method and found none. I might have to look in the source code.

Comment: It's the collector

Comment: “I was under the assumption that the resultant String would be null” Wrong assumption. Streams try very hard to eliminate nulls, in fact, that’s the whole point of the `Optional` type.

Comment: Also dug into the source code for joining - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l279

And prefix and suffix are empty strings and the behavior is supposed to use the prefix and suffix on empty streams, which also explains that.